# Why can't I force one of my Views to render in software?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-custom-view, hardware-acceleration

In a custom view I have, I'm using Canvas.drawBitmap with a source Bitmap that is wider than 2048px. This of course causes problems when Hardware Acceleration is enabled, with the LogCat spewing out "W/OpenGLRenderer(4968): Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture" each time drawBitmap is called.

So to work around this I tried calling `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)` on my view. The only problem is that it doesn't seem to help. When I try to run my app, LogCat will still give the warnings, and nothing ends up being drawn.

I cannot understand why is this so. [This article on the Android site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) clearly states:

> You can disable hardware acceleration for an individual view at runtime with the following code:
>
> ```
> myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
> ```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Why is Android not respecting the setLayerType call?

---

[in case it matters: I'm performing my testing on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 running Android 3.2]

Comment: Check canvas.isHardwareAccelerated(). It can be different from a view

Answer (score 0):

Try to resize the bitmap first. Use createBitmap.